# GRUB2 - Create 2nd boot entry with different kernel command line options in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

Tags: grub2

I want to have a separate boot menu entry at boot. The only difference is the value of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. The original (first) boot has empty value for GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, and the 2nd entry has a value that is passed to the kernel.

In short, I want to have two boot menu entries which the only difference is the kernel arguments. I poked around /etc/grub.d but couldn't find a way other than gross hack in /etc/grub.d.

Comment: Copy boot stanza into 40_custom and add whatever entries you want. With Ubuntu you can use the linked kernel files, so always booting most recent. See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MaintenanceFreeCustomGrub2Screen

Comment: It's not very portable. I do not like to hardcode the menu entry.

Comment: It is really dumb this is so hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this with rerunning /etc/grub.d/10_linux from /etc/grub.d/40_linux, and picking off the menu entry.

First part is /etc/grub.d/40_linux

```
#!/bin/sh
. /etc/default/grub
export GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY=true
export GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y
export GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=$GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT_ALT
/etc/grub.d/10_linux | python3 /usr/local/bin/extract-menuentry.py
```

So, I can rerun the 10_linux with alternate command line.

Put in the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT_ALT in the /etc/default/grub. (In my case, "aufs=tmpfs")

And wrote a python script to pick off the menu entry. (in /usr/local/bin/extract-menuentry.py in my case.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os, sys, re

menuentry_start = "menuentry"

def extract_menuentry(infile):
  in_menuentry = False
  for line in infile.readlines():
    if in_menuentry:
      if line.strip() == "}":
        in_menuentry = False
        print(line.rstrip())
        pass
      else:
        print(line.rstrip())
        pass
      pass
    else:
      if line.startswith(menuentry_start):
        in_menuentry = True
        match = re.search(r"menuentry '[^']+' (.*)", line)
        print("menuentry '%s' %s" % (os.environ.get('GRUB_ALT_NAME', 'Ubuntu alt'), match.group(1)))
        pass
      pass
    pass
  pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
  extract_menuentry(sys.stdin)
  pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I did on 16.04:

First add an entry for your alternate command line in `/etc/default/grub`<sup>1</sup>:

```
export GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_2="quiet splash mitigations=off"
```

Of course, change the content to reflect the arguments you'd like! **Note** that you need `export` as shown, even though the existing `GRUB_CMDLINE...` variables don't need it: because the existing known variables are exported somewhere else inside `grub-mkconfig`.

Second, edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` to add a new `linux_entry` line which will generate your new menu item. Where you put this in the file determines where it shows up, but to have it show up right below the first, default, option, but it here:

```
  if [ "x$is_top_level" = xtrue ] && [ "x${GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU}" != xy ]; then
    linux_entry "${OS}" "${version}" simple \
    "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT}"

    # START
    linux_entry "${OS} (mitigations off)" "${version}" simple \
    "${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_2}"
    # END
```

The newly added stuff is between `# START` and `# END` and the entry immediately above is the existing one that generates the default option. You could basically copy the prior entry, but change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_2`, and give it a unique name (in my case, I appended `(mitigations off}`).

Now this menu entry will be generated in the same way as the default entry, except using different command line args. You could also *add* to the default args with additional args, rather than replacing them, which is actually what I did, e.g.:

```
"${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT} ${GRUB_CMDLINE_EXTRA}"
```

where `${GRUB_CMDLINE_EXTRA}` are the extra args I wanted in addition to the default args.

Run `sudo update-grub` and you're good to go.

---

<sup>1</sup> Strictly speaking, you don't need this: you could just put the values directly into the `10_linux` `linux_entry` in the next step, but this keep things a bit clear and lets you create multiple entries with the new command line if you'd like. One problem is that you may occasionally get merge conflicts when `/etc/default/grub` gets updated (generally, they should be easy to resolve: you just want the default file plus your `export ...` line).

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:

1. Quick, easy, and with a GUI interface: install grub-customizer.

   ```
   sudo apt update && sudo apt install grub-customizer
   ```
2. Go into `/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts` and add a custom entry named custom1 (you can copy the configuration from your default entry in /boot/grub/grub.cfg)

   cd /etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts
   sudo leafpad custom1 &

The custom1 entry can look like this for example, and you can customize the default boot options in the line that starts with `linux`

```
menuentry "Custom Gnu/Linux"{
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5' [YOUR CORRESPONDING ROOT LOCATION]
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=[YOUR CORRESPONDING ROOT LOCATION] --hint-efi=[YOUR CORRESPONDING ROOT LOCATION] --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  [UUID of / partition]
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root [UUID]
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux custom1 ...'
    linux   /boot/[your vmlinuz] root=UUID=[UUID] ro initrd=/install/gtk/initrd.gz quiet splash acpi_osi=linux
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/[your initrd.img]
}
```

Then you have to edit (or create if not there) `40_custom_proxy` in `/etc/grub.d/` t

```sh
#!/bin/sh
#THIS IS A GRUB PROXY SCRIPT
'/etc/grub.d/proxifiedScripts/custom1' | /etc/grub.d/bin/grubcfg_proxy "-*
-#text
+'Custom1 Gnu/Linux'~f993006fab178e9acbf3ae439d2495c0~
```

and finally run `sudo grub-mkconfig` and `sudo update-grub`

However, option 1 is the one I would recommend, as it is cleaner faster and easier.